# NextJS - Cannot destructure property 'datasource' of 'props.fields.data' as it is undefined

Tags: jss, nextjs

Quiet new to NextJS JSS, I'm trying to create a NextJS component which uses integrated GraphQL. But I keep getting this error:

[image]

```
import { Text, Link, withDatasourceCheck } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
import { ComponentProps } from 'lib/component-props';
import NextLink from 'next/link';

type EX17IntegratedGraphQLProps = ComponentProps & {
  fields: {
    data: {
      datasource: {
        id: string,
        name: string,
        singleItem1: {
            name: string,
            id: string
        }
    }
      contextItem: {
          id: string;
          name: string;
      };
  };
  };
};

const EX17IntegratedGraphQL = (props: EX17IntegratedGraphQLProps): JSX.Element => {
  // Query results in integrated GraphQL replace the normal `fields` data
  // i.e. with { data, }
  console.log(props);
  const { datasource, contextItem } = props.fields.data;

  return (
    <div data-e2e-id="graphql-integrated">
      <h2>GraphQL Integrated Demo</h2>

      <p>
        Integrated GraphQL executes GraphQL queries within the Layout Service endpoint, and merges
        the query results into the Layout Service result JSON. The query results can be seen by
        inspecting the Layout Service response.
      </p>

      {datasource && (
        <div>
          <h4>Datasource Item (via Integrated GraphQL)</h4>
          id: {datasource.id}
          <br />
          name: {datasource.name}
          <br />
        </div>
      )}
      {contextItem && (
        <div>
          <h4>Route Item (via Integrated GraphQL)</h4>
          id: {contextItem.id}
          <br />
          page title: {contextItem.name}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withDatasourceCheck()<EX17IntegratedGraphQLProps>(EX17IntegratedGraphQL);
```

And this is GraphQL:

```
query ConnectedDemoQuery($datasource: String!, $contextItem: String!, $language: String!) {
  # Datasource query
  # $datasource should be set to the ID of the rendering's datasource item
  datasource: item(path: $datasource, language: $language) {
    id
    name
    ... on EX17IntegratedGraphQL{
        singleItem1{
            name,
            id
        }
    }
  }

  # Context/route item query
  # $contextItem should be set to the ID of the current context item (the route item)
  contextItem: item(path: $contextItem, language: $language) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

And this is JSS layout response:
[image]

Any hint would be good.

**UPDATE**
The same issue occurs when using the out of box sample graphQL route as well.
[image]

Comment: Instead of using the destructure, can you try using the following: `let source = props.fields?.datasource`

Comment: No luck. Same issue. Same error when you use out of box GraphQL sample:
http://localhost:3000/graphql

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve the issue?. Thanks Issue: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'datasource' of 'props.fields.data' as it is undefined. My Dev environment Details as follows
1.Sitecore Experience Platform 10.2 (Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) PowerShell module)
2.Sitecore Headless Services CD WDP for Sitecore XP
3.Sitecore Experience Edge Connector for Sitecore 10.2.0 XP 20.0.0
4.Sitecore Experience Accelerator 10.2.0 rev. 04247
5.Create a JSS project for the latest versions of JSS and Sitecore “npx create-sitecore-jss@ver20” Local certificate has b

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to re-create your issue. From my testing, it looks like you don't have the GraphQL query correctly stored in your rendering item.

For reference, this field needs to contain the GraphQL query. Depending on your workflow (Sitecore first or Code first) - you should either manually copy the GraphQL query from your post above to the field, or if you are running code first you can use the `jss deploy items` command to populate the rendering item.

[image]

Once I added the GraphQL query into the correct field, the component started to display the content correctly and the error goes away:

[image]

Thanks to [Justin Laster](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/170/justin-laster) for helping on this.

Comment: I checked the Component GraphQL Query, the query is definitely there.  Per above even JSS is also returning the correct results. But somehow the props on the component isn't picking up what jss layout service is returning.